# Energy conservation on SHM in springs

Tags: springs, homework

[image: Question diagram]

In the above spring block arrangements,  the time period is asked for $K_1=2K$ left spring  and $K_2=K$ right spring.

Now at equilibrium,
$$T=K_2x=Kx=mg$$
$$2T=K_1y=2Ky=2mg \implies x=y$$ for movable pulley.

**How does conservation of mechanical energy hold in spring block systems?**

For slow release(no KE change), loss in PE of block is stored in springs.
Since block moves by $2y+x=3x$ down
 2y because of movable pulley and x because of right spring
Then
$$mg(2y+x)=\frac{1}{2}K_1y^2+\frac{1}{2}K_2x^2$$
Using my initial force balance equation,
$$mg(3x)=mg(x)+\frac{mg(x)}{2}$$

Therefore energy is not conserved. What happened to the rest of it ? What did I do wrong?

Comment: "*For slow release(no KE change), loss in PE of block is stored in springs*". Can you justify this assumption with some citation?

Comment: Can you use force equilibrium after you move weight into another position? I think there is only one static equilibrium, other ones will be dynamic and the weight will have to accelerate. Or you can hold it there using external force.